# How do I use a view parameter as a field in native Foxpro SQL statement

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

I am using VFEGenview to create my view. The view I am trying to create has complex joins so I can not use VFP's View Designer because it would mess up my joins. Using VFEGenView and just trying to create a simple view to test inclusion of a view parameters value as a field in my view, I get an error.

My code:

```
DBSetProp('VL_CUSTOMERS', 'View', 'ParameterList', "vp_ccommmenus_id,'C'")

CREATE SQL VIEW "VL_Customers" ;    
AS 
    SELECT Customers.cid,;
        Customers.ccustomer_number,;        Customers.ccustomer_name,;
        ?vp_commmenus_id as ccommmenus_id;  FROM INMATETRUSTFUND!Customers
```

I have tried `:?vp_commmenus_id`, `&?vp_commmenus_id` and `&vp_commmenus_id` all of which result in an error:

> vp_commmenus_id is not found

Thanks, John

Comment: you can't use parameters as always for that that use strung concatenation to produce string which ypu run as command see https://flylib.com/books/en/2.920.1.14/1/

Comment: Marc_s, I read the entire link and did not find the solution. I do not understand your answer.

Comment: look for the chapter *Creating Views with Stored SQL SELECT Statements* there you see where a string was defined and used to create a view. you need to add your column to a sql string and use that like the chapter describes

Comment: marc_s, I hate being a pest but I can not find that chapter. Is that the exact chapter name? Thanks, John

Comment: first i am not marc_s, second there i really can't help you, read it slow and carefully from the beginning it is in the first chapter creating views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are superfluous line-continuation characters ";" in the code you posted. But first of all, a Vfp SQL View Parameter needs to be in scope in the very moment when you want "use" it, i.e. when the "Create [SQL] View ..." statement runs in your case, as well as when you open it, i.e. `Use theView`, or when you would `Requery("theView")`.

Just tried the following sequence in the Vfp "Command Window":

```
* first Change Directory to the desired "Test" File-System folder:
CD D:\Temp
CREATE DATABASE Test55
CREATE TABLE test56 (col1 Int)
INSERT INTO test56 VALUES (8)

CREATE VIEW vTest as Select col1, ?p1 From test56 && throws an Error 1806 as you noted

p1 = "x" && create the variable first
CREATE VIEW vTest as Select col1, ?p1 From test56 && works now

USE vtest
BROWSE
```

[image]

Comment: First, To nbk, sorry about the names mixup. Got it.

Comment: Stefan, I use the VFE framework and I am not sure exactly when the view parameters get created because it all sort of happens magically. I know from my testing it was not in existence when I needed it to be. The short version of my answer is that you are correct with your example. I created a variable similarly named to my view parameter and just before I create the view I loaded the local variable with the same value as I load into the view parameter and then used the local variable in the sql and voila it worked just as you stated. Thanks all, John

Comment: @vfpjohn , glad to hear you got it working